# html file displaying wierd characters when copied from Windows to Mac

Tags: html, windows, macos, file, cross-platform

Ok, I think the title pretty much sums the question up nicely. Basically, I've written an help file on my windows machine in HTML, so it includes characters like the following:
`®`, `'`, `"`, `...`

Obviously it displays fine on Windows, but when I copy the file to my Mac and try to view it the characters above turn jibberish and look foriegn. I could type them on my Mac and save it, but I'm just worried that I need to do something to prevent the same thing from happening on other computers/environments.

If anybody knows how I can stop this from happening, as easily as possible, I'd be greatful to know. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your HTML file is saved as UTF8 and use the UTF8 meta tag:

- To save a file as UTF-8, open it in using NotePad and choose "save as", then make sure encoding is set as UTF-8.
- To add the UTF-8 meta tag to your HTML file, just add the following line in the "head" section: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

UTF8 is designed for backward compatibility with ASCII and to avoid the complications of endianness and byte order marks in UTF-16 and UTF-32. See: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is either due to file encoding (maybe one uses UTF-8 and the other iso-8859-1) or due to differences between editors. Try on the Windows machine pasting the code into Notepad or Wordpad, then sending that code to the Mac.

Comment: Thank you as well. Your assumption was correct but I've accepted John's answer because it is more complete!

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as unicode and add the meta like John Riche said or replace it by its HTML entities:

```
&reg; = ®
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp